# Saber tamaño de varios ficheros

Tags: java

Tengo una duda, he echo un programa que me verifica varias características de todos los ficheros de un directorio.

En este caso necesito saber los byte y el nombre.

Pero el tamaño no sé como hacerlo, en todos lados leo que es con Lenght pero a mi no me funciona, que hago mal?

Código:

```
           File[] ficheros = miDir.listFiles();            
for (int x=0;x<ficheros.length;x++){
  System.out.print( ficheros.length+ "                  ");
  System.out.println(ficheros[x].getName());

}
```

Es decir el resultado final debería de ser el siguiente:

BYTE                   FICHERO

1430                    fichero X

( Donde pongo 1430 y fichero X es información de ejemplo)

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola lo que sucede es que tu estas obteniendo el largo de tu arreglo , tu codigo debiese quedar similar a esto :

```
    File[] ficheros = miDir.listFiles();
    for (int x = 0; x < ficheros.length; x++) 
    {
        System.out.println( ficheros[x].getName() +" "+ ficheros[x].length());
    }
```